# Generating all Possible Combinations

Tags: c#, combinatorics, cartesian-product

Given 2 arrays `Array1 = {a,b,c...n}` and `Array2 = {10,20,15....x}` how can I generate all possible combination as Strings **a(i) b(j) c(k) n(p)** 
where

```
1 <= i <= 10,  1 <= j <= 20 , 1 <= k <= 15,  .... 1 <= p <= x
```

Such as:

```
a1 b1 c1 .... n1  
a1 b1 c1..... n2  
......  
......  
a10 b20 c15 nx (last combination)
```

So in all total number of combination = product of elements of `array2 = 
(10 X 20 X 15 X ..X x)`

Similar to a Cartesian product, in which the second array defines the upper limit for each element in first array.

Example with fixed numbers,

```
    Array x =  [a,b,c]
    Array y =  [3,2,4]
```

So we will have 3*2*4 = 24 combinations. Results should be:

```
    a1 b1 c1  
    a1 b1 c2  
    a1 b1 c3  
    a1 b1 c4  

    a1 b2 c1  
    a1 b2 c2  
    a1 b2 c3  
    a1 b2 c4


    a2 b1 c1  
    a2 b1 c2  
    a2 b1 c3  
    a2 b1 c4  

    a2 b2 c1  
    a2 b2 c2  
    a2 b2 c3  
    a2 b2 c4


    a3 b1 c1  
    a3 b1 c2  
    a3 b1 c3  
    a3 b1 c4  

    a3 b2 c1  
    a3 b2 c2  
    a3 b2 c3  
    a3 b2 c4 (last)
```

Comment: Can you give a better example, using fewer elements, and produce the full results? For instance, one question I have is whether each element of the first array should be paired only with the corresponding element of the second array, or if you want to combine it with all elements of the second array.

Comment: Probably the size of the arrays are same.

Comment: yes 2 arrays are of same size..

Comment: Eric blogged about this just for you :) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

Comment: Updated link to the post @Ahmed referenced: https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public static string[] GenerateCombinations(string[] Array1, int[] Array2)
{
    if(Array1 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Array1");
    if(Array2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Array2");
    if(Array1.Length != Array2.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be the same size as Array1.", "Array2");

    if(Array1.Length == 0)
        return new string[0];

    int outputSize = 1;
    var current = new int[Array1.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < current.Length; ++i)
    {
        if(Array2[i] < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Contains invalid values.", "Array2");
        if(Array1[i] == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Contains null values.", "Array1");
        outputSize *= Array2[i];
        current[i] = 1;
    }

    var result = new string[outputSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < outputSize; ++i)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int j = 0; j < current.Length; ++j)
        {
            sb.Append(Array1[j]);
            sb.Append(current[j].ToString());
            if(j != current.Length - 1)
                sb.Append(' ');
        }
        result[i] = sb.ToString();
        int incrementIndex = current.Length - 1;
        while(incrementIndex >= 0 && current[incrementIndex] == Array2[incrementIndex])
        {
                current[incrementIndex] = 1;
                --incrementIndex;
        }
        if(incrementIndex >= 0)
            ++current[incrementIndex];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 169):

Sure thing. It is a bit tricky to do this with LINQ but certainly possible using only the standard query operators.

UPDATE: This is the subject of [my blog on Monday June 28th 2010](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/); thanks for the great question. Also, a commenter on my blog noted that there is an even more elegant query than the one I gave.  I'll update the code here to use it.

The tricky part is to make the Cartesian product of arbitrarily many sequences. "Zipping" in the letters is trivial compared to that. You should study this to make sure that you understand how it works. Each part is simple enough but the way they are combined together takes some getting used to:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>()};
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) => 
            from accseq in accumulator 
            from item in sequence 
            select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})                          
        );
 }
```

To explain how this works, first understand what the "accumulate" operation is doing. The simplest accumulate operation is "add everything in this sequence together". The way you do that is: start with zero. For each item in the sequence, the current value of the accumulator is equal to the sum of the item and previous value of the accumulator.  We're doing the same thing, except that instead of accumulating the sum based on the sum so far and the current item, we're accumulating the Cartesian product as we go.

The way we're going to do that is to take advantage of the fact that we already have an operator in LINQ that computes the Cartesian product of two things:

```
from x in xs
from y in ys
do something with each possible (x, y)
```

By repeatedly taking the Cartesian product of the accumulator with the next item in the input sequence and doing a little pasting together of the results, we can generate the Cartesian product as we go.

So think about the value of the accumulator. For illustrative purposes I'm going to show the value of the accumulator as the *results* of the sequence operators it contains. That is not what the accumulator *actually* contains. What the accumulator actually contains is the *operators* that produce these results. The whole operation here just builds up a *massive* tree of sequence operators, the result of which is the Cartesian product.  But *the final Cartesian product itself is not actually computed until the query is executed.*  For illustrative purposes I'll show what the *results* are at each stage of the way but remember, this actually contains the *operators* that produce those results.

Suppose we are taking the Cartesian product of the sequence of sequences `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}`. The accumulator starts off as a sequence containing one empty sequence: `{ { } }`

On the first accumulation, accumulator is { { } } and item is {1, 2}. We do this:

```
from accseq in accumulator
from item in sequence 
select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})
```

So we are taking the Cartesian product of `{ { } }` with `{1, 2}`, and for each pair, we concatenate:  We have the pair `({ }, 1)`, so we concatenate `{ }` and `{1}` to get `{1}`. We have the pair `({ }, 2})`, so we concatenate `{ }` and `{2}` to get `{2}`. Therefore we have `{{1}, {2}}` as the result.

So on the second accumulation, accumulator is `{{1}, {2}}` and item is `{3, 4}`. Again, we compute the Cartesian product of these two sequences to get:

```
 {({1}, 3), ({1}, 4), ({2}, 3), ({2}, 4)}
```

and then from those items, concatenate the second one onto the first. So the result is the sequence `{{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}`, which is what we want.

Now we accumulate again. We take the Cartesian product of the accumulator with `{5, 6}` to get

```
 {({ 1, 3}, 5), ({1, 3}, 6), ({1, 4}, 5), ...
```

and then concatenate the second item onto the first to get:

```
{{1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 6} ... }
```

and we're done. We've accumulated the Cartesian product.

Now that we have a utility function that can take the Cartesian product of arbitrarily many sequences, the rest is easy by comparison:

```
var arr1 = new[] {"a", "b", "c"};
var arr2 = new[] { 3, 2, 4 };
var result = from cpLine in CartesianProduct(
                 from count in arr2 select Enumerable.Range(1, count)) 
             select cpLine.Zip(arr1, (x1, x2) => x2 + x1);
```

And now we have a sequence of sequences of strings, one sequence of strings per line:

```
foreach (var line in result)
{
    foreach (var s in line)
        Console.Write(s);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Easy peasy!

Comment: @FlorisDevriendt: You're welcome. You have discovered why it is a good idea to try to make a *small complete example that demonstrates the problem*.  **Doing so usually solves the problem.**  Another technique that works is to obtain a rubber duck, and then explain, out loud, the exact problem to the rubber duck. In doing so it is very common to discover the answer, whether the duck knows it or not.

Comment: @EricLippert, That seems to be a perfect explanation and excellent solution, but I have to explore it a little more deeply before saying I understand ok. In the meantime...  Do you know 2 things: 1 - Does the solution is recursive which could create quickly a stack overflow? 2 - Does it create a very large array of possibilities which could also be a memory problem? Or does it uses a combination of 'a minimum of states in memory' and 'yield keyword' in order to stay low in memory?

Comment: @EricOuellet: (1) You can work out whether this is recursive. Every recursive function has the same form: first handle a base case if the problem is simple, otherwise make one or more simpler problems, solve them with a recursive call, and combine the solutions into the solution to the larger problem.  **Does this method follow that pattern?**

Comment: @EricOuellet: Plainly the method itself is not recursive. But there are other ways of producing a stack overflow other than recursion.  There *is* an arbitrarily deep call stack here, but it is well hidden. **Can you find it**?

Comment: @EricOuellet: Regarding (2), plainly this allocates an enormous number of objects to construct the final accumulation.  None of them are large arrays though; the only arrays that are constructed are single element arrays. **Can you characterize the number of objects created by this solution as a function of the size of the input? How about the output?**

Comment: @EricLippert, The number of every combinaison is n! (factorial). It become quite big quite fast. That's why I ask about memory or recursion. Sometimes the recursion could be hidden, the pattern is not necessarily visible. But I will definitively take the time to understand and experiment your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @EricOuellet: The number of combinations is not n! for the cartesian product. Rather, if we have sequences of size a, b, c, d... then the number of combinations is a x b x c x d ...  That also gets very big very fast!  However in this case we will find that the deepest the recursion goes is n, where n is the number of sequences being combined.  So that's unbounded, but it is very unlikely to be even in the dozens, much less in the thousands.

Comment: @EricOuellet: In analyzing this algorithm, start by considering (1) what is the total memory and time burden of each instance of that query expression *before the query is executed*?  and (2) what precisely is the output of the aggregation step, again *before the resulting sequence is enumerated*. I have deliberately not talked about that in the analysis above; can you work out what the "shape" of the thing returned by Aggregate actually is? It will be necessary to have a clear understanding of how Aggregate is implemented, so take a look at the code.

Comment: @EricLippert, I'm very sorry. I didn't read properly. I though that it would give all possible combinaison for an array of objects. Ex: {a,b,c} => abc, acb, bac,bca, cab, cba. But I was wrong. But I will read your article (seems very interesting) very soon and try to find an answer. Thank you very much for your support. I can't do it now because it is for a personal project and I'm at work.

Comment: @EricOuellet: If that subject interests you, see https://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/

Answer (score 13):

Alternative solution:

Step one: read my series of articles on how to generate all strings which match a context sensitive grammar:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906105746/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/grammars/)

Step two: define a grammar that generates the language you want. For example, you could define the grammar:

```
S: a A b B c C
A: 1 | 2 | 3
B: 1 | 2
C: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

Clearly you can easily generate that grammar definition string from your two arrays. Then feed that into the code which generates all strings in a given grammar, and you're done; you'll get all the possibilities.  (Not necessesarily in the order you want them in, mind you.)

Comment: order isn't important for now...but can grammars be used to generate a sequence in a particular order ?

Answer (score 7):

Using [`Enumerable.Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append), which was added in .NET Framework 4.7.1, @EricLippert's answer can be implemented without allocating a new array at each iteration:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>
    (this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> enumerables)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Seed() { yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>(); }

    return enumerables.Aggregate(Seed(), (accumulator, enumerable)
        => accumulator.SelectMany(x => enumerable.Select(x.Append)));
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer - the use of the method group makes what is happening very clear.

Comment: I would note though it isn't really lighter weight than the original answer because the `Enumerable.Append` method creates a linked list of chained objects to track the appends, which is probably more overhead than an array with one element.

Answer (score 3):

Fon another solution not linq based you can use:

```
public class CartesianProduct<T>
    {
        int[] lengths;
        T[][] arrays;
        public CartesianProduct(params  T[][] arrays)
        {
            lengths = arrays.Select(k => k.Length).ToArray();
            if (lengths.Any(l => l == 0))
                throw new ArgumentException("Zero lenght array unhandled.");
            this.arrays = arrays;
        }
        public IEnumerable<T[]> Get()
        {
            int[] walk = new int[arrays.Length];
            int x = 0;
            yield return walk.Select(k => arrays[x++][k]).ToArray();
            while (Next(walk))
            {
                x = 0;
                yield return walk.Select(k => arrays[x++][k]).ToArray();
            }

        }
        private bool Next(int[] walk)
        {
            int whoIncrement = 0;
            while (whoIncrement < walk.Length)
            {
                if (walk[whoIncrement] < lengths[whoIncrement] - 1)
                {
                    walk[whoIncrement]++;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    walk[whoIncrement] = 0;
                    whoIncrement++;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You can find an example on [how to use it here](http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/08/12/HelperClassForTheCartesianProductOfMoreThanTwoArrays.aspx).

Comment: This worked very well for me when the amount of arrays is only known at run time!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not willing to give you the complete source code. So here's the idea behind.

You can generate the elements the following way:

I assume `A=(a1, a2, ..., an)` and `B=(b1, b2, ..., bn)` (so `A` and `B` each hold `n` elements).

Then do it recursively! Write a method that takes an `A` and a `B` and does your stuff:

If `A` and `B` each contain just one element (called `an` resp. `bn`), just iterate from 1 to `bn` and concatenate `an` to your iterating variable.

If `A` and `B` each contain more then one element, grab the first elements (`a1` resp `b1`), iterate from 1 to `bn` and do for each iteration step:

- call the method recursively with the subfields of `A` and `B` starting at the second element, i.e. `A'=(a2, a3, ..., an)` resp `B'=(b2, b3, ..., bn)`. For every element generated by the recursive call, concatenate `a1`, the iterating variable and the generated element from the recursive call.

[Here](http://talkingfrogsw.blogspot.com/2009/01/this-article-will-demonstrate-simple.html) you can find an analouge example of how to generate things in C#, you "just" have to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting it right, you are after something like **[Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)**. 
If this is the case here is you how you can do this using LINQ. Might not be exact answer but try to get the idea

---

```
    char[] Array1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    string[] Array2 = { "10", "20", "15" };

    var result = from i in Array1
                 from j in Array2
                   select i + j;
```

---

These Articles might help

- **[SelectMany](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/selectmany-probably-the-most-p)**
- **[How to Use LINQ SelectMany](http://blog.linqexchange.com/index.php/how-to-use-linq-selectmany/)**

Comment: No, his possible "combinations" (poor choice of words on the OP's part, IMO) are not just the Cartesian product of the two sets. The second array defines an upper boundary, not the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

The finalResult is the desired array. Assumed the both arrays are of same size.

```
char[] Array1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
int[] Array2 = { 3, 2, 4 };

var finalResult = new List<string>();
finalResult.Add(String.Empty);
for(int i=0; i<Array1.Length; i++)
{
    var tmp = from a in finalResult
              from b in Enumerable.Range(1,Array2[i])
              select String.Format("{0} {1}{2}",a,Array1[i],b).Trim();
    finalResult = tmp.ToList();
}
```

I think this will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Fon another solution not linq based, more effective:

```
static IEnumerable<T[]> CartesianProduct<T>(T[][] arrays) {
    int[] lengths;
    lengths = arrays.Select(a => a.Length).ToArray();
    int Len = arrays.Length;
    int[] inds = new int[Len];
    int Len1 = Len - 1;
    while (inds[0] != lengths[0]) {
        T[] res = new T[Len];
        for (int i = 0; i != Len; i++) {
            res[i] = arrays[i][inds[i]];
        }
        yield return res;
        int j = Len1;
        inds[j]++;
        while (j > 0 && inds[j] == lengths[j]) {
            inds[j--] = 0;
            inds[j]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in industrial, tested, and supported implementation of Cartesian Product algorithm, you are welcome to use a ready-to-use [Gapotchenko.FX.Math.Combinatorics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gapotchenko.FX.Math.Combinatorics/) NuGet package.

It provides two modes of operation. A fluent mode which is LINQ-based:

```
using Gapotchenko.FX.Math.Combinatorics;
using System;

foreach (var i in new[] { "1", "2" }.CrossJoin(new[] { "A", "B", "C" }))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", i));
```

And an explicit mode, which is more verbose:

```
using Gapotchenko.FX.Math.Combinatorics;
using System;

var seq1 = new[] { "1", "2" };
var seq2 = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };

foreach (var i in CartesianProduct.Of(seq1, seq2))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", i));
```

Both modes produce the same result:

```
1 A
2 A
1 B
2 B
1 C
2 C
```

But it goes further than this. For example, a projection to `ValueTuple` results is a simple one-liner:

```
var results = new[] { 1, 2 }.CrossJoin(new[] { "A", "B" }, ValueTuple.Create);

foreach (var (a, b) in results)
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", a, b);
```

The uniqueness of the results can be achieved in a natural way:

```
var results = new[] { 1, 1, 2 }.CrossJoin(new[] { "A", "B", "A" }).Distinct();
```

From the first sight, such an approach would produce an excessive waste of combinations. So instead of doing

```
new[] { 1, 1, 2 }.CrossJoin(new[] { "A", "B", "A" }).Distinct()
```

it might be more beneficial to `Distinct()` the sequences before performing the expensive multiplication:

```
new[] { 1, 1, 2 }.Distinct().CrossJoin(new[] { "A", "B", "A" }.Distinct())
```

The package provides an automatic plan builder that optimizes away such idiosyncrasies. As a result, both approaches have identical computational complexity.

The corresponding source code of the package is a bit larger than a snippet can contain, but is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/gapotchenko/Gapotchenko.FX/tree/master/Source/Gapotchenko.FX.Math.Combinatorics).

Answer (score 0):

The most voted answer is excellent, but doesn't make it explicit that this is in fact joining two strings of vector, where even if the operand is `IEnumerable<T>`, it shall be regarded as `IEnumerable<(T)>`, i.e., a string of 1-tuple.

To make this theoretically (not necessarily practically )  aesthetic, I would recommend to implement it as follows:

First, implement a binary operator:

```
public interface BinaryI<T>
{
    T op(T,T);
}

public class Cartesian<T> :BinaryI<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> op(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> par, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> par1)
    {
        return  from x in par
            from y in par1
            select x.Concat(y)
        ;
    }
}
```

Then extend that into a Cumulator:

```
public class Cumulator<T,TOp> where TOp:BinaryI<T>
{
    private T _initial;
    public T initial { get { return _initial; } }
    private TOp _binder;
    public TOp binder { get { return _binder; } }
    public Cumulator(T initial, TOp binder)
    {
        _initial = initial;
        _binder = binder;
    }

    public T cumulate(IEnumerable<T> seq)
    {
        return  seq.Aggregate(initial, _binder.op);
    }
}
```

Then you could use it:

```
var accumulator = new Cumulator<IEnumerable<T>,BinaryI<T>>(new[]{Enumerable.Empty<T>()}, new Cartesian<T>());
cumulator.cumulate ((IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>) (something));
```

The above is excerpted and adapted from some of our production code; some interim types in the process of inheritance are made shorter for this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here's is a javascript version, which I'm sure someone can convert. It has been tested thoroughly.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobberino/WeD94/).

```
function combinations (Asource){

    var combos = [];
    var temp = [];

    var picker = function (arr, temp_string, collect) {
        if (temp_string.length) {
           collect.push(temp_string);
        }

        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            var arrcopy = arr.slice(0, arr.length);
            var elem = arrcopy.splice(i, 1);

            if (arrcopy.length > 0) {
                picker(arrcopy, temp_string.concat(elem), collect);
            } else {
                collect.push(temp_string.concat(elem));
            }   
        }   
    }

    picker(Asource, temp, combos);

    return combos;

}

var todo = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]; // 5 in this set
var resultingCombos = combinations (todo);
console.log(resultingCombos);
```

Comment: Why is this here? The question is about C#. JavaScript has its own Cartesian Product threads, for example, [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript). This should be posted there.