# Group items in pairs

Tags: linq

I have list of items, for example: `{ i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7 }`.
I want to get a list, where every item is a pair of items from source list: `{ {i1, i2}, {i3, i4}, {i5, i6}, {i7} }`.
`i7` is a single item in pair because there is no item `i8`.
Is it possible to do with LINQ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Objects - return pairs of numbers from list of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461367/linq-to-objects-return-pairs-of-numbers-from-list-of-numbers)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, you *could* do:

```
var pairs = sequence.Select((value, index) => new { value, index } )
                    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2, x => x.value)
```

The result is an `IGrouping<int, T>` with a key of 0, 1, 2 etc and the contents of each group being one or two items.

However, I'd possibly write a custom extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> PairUp<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            var first = iterator.Current;
            var second = iterator.MoveNext() ? iterator.Current : default(T);
            yield return Tuple.Create(first, second);
        }
    }
}
```

This will yield a sequence of tuples - the downside here is that the final tuple will have the default value for `T` as the "second" item if the sequence has an odd number of items. For reference types where the sequence only consists of non-null values, that's okay, but for some sequences it wouldn't help.

Comment: There is a bug in your first LINQ query - it should be x.index \ 2 instead of x.index / 2.

Comment: @J.Polfer: That wouldn't be valid C#. Perhaps you were expecting VB?

Comment: True, I am working in VB right now... you need to use \ if you are using VB to do integer division.  Nevermind.