# Convert a List<int> to a List<Point> with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Given an even-sized `List<int>` and a `List<Point>`

```
List<int> coords = new List<int> (){23, 137, 76, 151, 61, 203};
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
```

I know I can do it the old-fashioned way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coords.Count; i += 2) points.Add(new Point(coords[i], coords[i+1]));
```

..but I wonder if there is a nice LINQ way to do this conversion?

Comment: There probably is a way, but I really don't see why it would be an improvement over the for loop...

Comment: There is, but why? LINQ is slower and not always as easy to read. Only use it if it actually simplifies code and adds value.

Comment: There is no easy way to do it with standart LINQ methods. Your implementation is pretty clean. Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461367/linq-to-objects-return-pairs-of-numbers-from-list-of-numbers)

Comment: Do you think this is cleaner? `var list = coords.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0)
                        .Zip(coords.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 1), (x, y) => new Point(x, y))
                        .ToList();`

Comment: I was __curious__ about the ways to use LINQ, which I often find quite amazing.

Comment: Not really Linq, but you can do it with `yield` keyword. Attempting to do this in linq will make the code worse.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Why not? it wasn't based on index value, but the index itself

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Maybe I'm missing something, but if my solution was based on the index (not the value stored in the index), how can affect {1,1,1,1,1,1}? It doesn't matter. Now I understand the downvote: some readers don't read :D

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Nevermind, the code was too buggy and faulty. I've completely deleted it. This happens when you try to solve an answer some minutes before going to bed.. argh :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
var points = coords.Select((v,i) => new {v,i})
    .GroupBy(x => x.i/2)
    .Select(x => new Point(x.First().v, x.Last().v))
    .ToList();
```

**Update**: Actually this should be solved with the [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1) command:

```
var points = coords.Skip(1).Zip(coords, 
                               (second, first) => new Point(first, second) ).ToArray();
```

Comment: Mark's answer will be considerably more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Well, one way would be the following:

```
List<int> coords = new List<int> (){23, 137, 76, 151, 61, 203};
List<Point> points = Enumerable.Range(0, coords.Count / 2)
    .Select(i => new Point(coords[i * 2], coords[(i * 2) + 1]))
    .ToList();
```

There are probably a dozen other ways as well, however, I think that in this case a simple for-loop is really the most concise and clear solution.

Comment: I think you meant to use `i*2`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not LINQ, but you could create your own extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Point> ToPoints(this List<int> source)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i += 2)
    {
        yield return new Point(source[i], source[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Point> points = coords.ToPoints().ToList();
```

Is that LINQ-y enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Batch` method, from [`MoreLINQ`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library:

```
List<int> coords = new List<int> (){23, 137, 76, 151, 61, 203};
var points = coords
          .Batch(2)
          .Select(x => new Point(x.First(), x.Last())
          .ToList();
```