# How do I create a custom ordered array from a list?

Tags: c#

I have a list that returns my data in the following format:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

What if I wanted to return an array in the following format? :

```
[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]
```

Here's what I have written up so far:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();            
            foreach (var record in model.rows)
            {
                list.Add(record[0]);
                list.Add(record[1]);                  
            }

            Console.WriteLine(list);
```

Comment: What if the list holds an odd number of values?

Comment: Duplicate-to-duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461367/linq-to-objects-return-pairs-of-numbers-from-list-of-numbers) asks exactly your question if you need copy-paste ready solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you want is a list of arrays. You could try this:

```
List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>();

for(int i = 0; i < model.Length; i++)
    list.Add(new[] { model[i], i+1 >= model.Length ? 0 : model[++i] });
```

The `++i` operator will increment the value of `i` and read. SO, the second element of the array is defined by an check if the i+1 is greater than the length of `model` collection. If yes, the `0` is set, otherwise the next element of the `model` selection.

Comment: faster on the draw than me! Do you need to increment i by two instead of one in your for loop?

Comment: this will throw an index out of range exception on the last row.

Comment: @rlb.usa No, because the `++i` will also increment `i`.  You would if you used `i+1` instead.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Only  if there are an odd number of items in `record`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled you are right, if the number of items on `model` is odd, it will throw an exception. If add an adjust to avoid it and will edit my anwser to explain.