# Dictionary grouping issue

Tags: c#, dictionary

My code only works for the first set of group on the left and not the other group on the right and its giving me an error : "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

What is the right code to get the second group starting with MAJOR_PSIST?

Here's my code:

```
        var data = File
        .ReadAllLines(textfiletest)
        .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
        .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
        .GroupBy(x => x[0].Trim())
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First()[1]);
```

Here's my text file {textfiletest}

```
   MINOR_PSIST                    : 2          MAJOR_PSIST                    : 8        
   CRITICAL_PSIST                 : 60         ECSFB_CALL_CONTROL_TYPE        : AUTOMATIC
   CALL_CONTROL_TYPE              : AUTOMATIC  REGI_CONTROL_TYPE              : AUTOMATIC
   PAGE_CONTROL_TYPE              : AUTOMATIC  THRESHOLD_TIME                 : 1        
   ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL   : 0          CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL    : 0        
   REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL    : 0          PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL    : 1800     
   ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR    : 25         CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR     : 25       
   REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR     : 50         PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR     : 25       
   ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR    : 20         CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR     : 20       
   REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR     : 40         PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR     : 5        
   ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL : 15         CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL  : 15       
   REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL  : 30         PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL  : 1        
   UNIT_SECOND_INTERVAL           : 3        
   RESULT = OK
 COMPLETED
```

Comment: Your code did not throw any exception when I executed it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to group the second column by group key. See if the code given below works.

```
var data = File
    .ReadAllLines(textfiletest)
    .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
    .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
    .GroupBy(x => x[0].Trim())
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified @Strilanc's (Thanks :) ) extension function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461367/linq-to-objects-return-pairs-of-numbers-from-list-of-numbers) post:

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T[]> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int partitionSize)
        {
            var buffer = new T[partitionSize];
            var n = 0;
            foreach (var item in sequence)
            {
                buffer[n] = item;
                n += 1;
                if (n == partitionSize)
                {
                    yield return buffer;
                    buffer = new T[partitionSize];
                    n = 0;
                }
            }
            //partial leftovers
            if (n > 0) yield return buffer;
        }
    }
```

And this is the code:

```
var file = @"MINOR_PSIST                    : 2          MAJOR_PSIST                    : 8        
   CRITICAL_PSIST                 : 60         ECSFB_CALL_CONTROL_TYPE        : AUTOMATIC
   CALL_CONTROL_TYPE              : AUTOMATIC  REGI_CONTROL_TYPE              : AUTOMATIC
   PAGE_CONTROL_TYPE              : AUTOMATIC  THRESHOLD_TIME                 : 1        
   ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL   : 0          CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL    : 0        
   REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL    : 0          PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL    : 1800     
   ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR    : 25         CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR     : 25       
   REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR     : 50         PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR     : 25       
   ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR    : 20         CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR     : 20       
   REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR     : 40         PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR     : 5        
   ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL : 15         CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL  : 15       
   REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL  : 30         PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL  : 1        
   UNIT_SECOND_INTERVAL           : 3        
   RESULT = OK
 COMPLETED";



var lines = file.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
                Select(l => l.Split(new char[2] { ' ', ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).
                Where(l => l.Length % 2 == 0). // don't take the Result = OK\Completed lines -> Change this condition if you need to
                SelectMany(line => line.Partition(2)).
                GroupBy(kvp => kvp.First()).
                ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Select(g => g.Last()).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have to separate each group out from each line before you can create your `Dictionary`.  It looks like the first group is 42 characters in length, so we can break each group apart using `String.Substring()`.

Once each group is broken apart, then you can build your `Dictionary` using `Linq`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> fileLines = new List<string>
        {
            "MINOR_PSIST                    : 2          MAJOR_PSIST                    : 8        ",
            "CRITICAL_PSIST                 : 60         ECSFB_CALL_CONTROL_TYPE        : AUTOMATIC",
            "CALL_CONTROL_TYPE              : AUTOMATIC  REGI_CONTROL_TYPE              : AUTOMATIC",
            "PAGE_CONTROL_TYPE              : AUTOMATIC  THRESHOLD_TIME                 : 1        ",
            "ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL   : 0          CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL    : 0        ",
            "REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL    : 0          PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL    : 1800     ",
            "ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR    : 25         CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR     : 25       ",
            "REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR     : 50         PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR     : 25       ",
            "ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR    : 20         CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR     : 20       ",
            "REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR     : 40         PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR     : 5        ",
            "ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL : 15         CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL  : 15       ",
            "REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL  : 30         PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL  : 1        ",
            "UNIT_SECOND_INTERVAL           : 3          ",
            "RESULT = OK",
            "COMPLETED  "
        };

        // Each group contains a colon
        var groupLines = fileLines.Where(line => line.Contains(":"));

        // Break out each group to its own line
        List<string> groups = new List<string>();
        foreach (string line in groupLines)
        {
            groups.Add(line.Substring(0, 42));
            if (line.Length > 44)
            {
                groups.Add(line.Substring(44));
            }
        }

        // Build the dictionary from the groups
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = groups.Select(line => line.Split(':'))
            .GroupBy(pieces => pieces[0].Trim(), pieces => pieces[1].Trim())
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.First());

        // Print the dictionary to verify success
        foreach (var r in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0,-35} Value: {1}", r.Key, r.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Key: MINOR_PSIST                         Value: 2
Key: MAJOR_PSIST                         Value: 8
Key: CRITICAL_PSIST                      Value: 60
Key: ECSFB_CALL_CONTROL_TYPE             Value: AUTOMATIC
Key: CALL_CONTROL_TYPE                   Value: AUTOMATIC
Key: REGI_CONTROL_TYPE                   Value: AUTOMATIC
Key: PAGE_CONTROL_TYPE                   Value: AUTOMATIC
Key: THRESHOLD_TIME                      Value: 1
Key: ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL        Value: 0
Key: CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL         Value: 0
Key: REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL         Value: 0
Key: PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_NORMAL         Value: 1800
Key: ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR         Value: 25
Key: CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR          Value: 25
Key: REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR          Value: 50
Key: PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MINOR          Value: 25
Key: ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR         Value: 20
Key: CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR          Value: 20
Key: REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR          Value: 40
Key: PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_MAJOR          Value: 5
Key: ECSFB_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL      Value: 15
Key: CALL_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL       Value: 15
Key: REGI_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL       Value: 30
Key: PAGE_PER_UNIT_SEC_IN_CRITICAL       Value: 1
Key: UNIT_SECOND_INTERVAL                Value: 3
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B6z0AJ)

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your effort but I need to use this file: string textfiletest = "C:/BSM_Command_v2.txt" I appreciate your help on this program

Comment: @LacsonNoelLacky If the file is in the same format as posted in your question, then adapt the code in the answer to get the data from your file and store the file in a List<string>.  Everything else should work after that.