# Three text box all line join in list of string

Tags: vb.net

I want to do is just like string join with three text box all line will be merge here's my sample

Textbox1.Text lines:

```
Sample1
Sample2
Sample3
```

Textbox2.Text lines:

```
: (seperator)
```

Textbox3 lines:

```
Pass1
Pass2
Pass3
```

Here's my code for merging all text box

```
For Each str As String In Me.right.Lines
    For Each str2 As String In Me.sep.Text
        For Each str3 As String In Me.left.Lines
            If Not str2 = "" Then

                '(change into list of string) 
                sam.Text += str + str2 + str3 & vbNewLine
            Else

                '(change into list of string)
                sam.Text += str + str3 & vbNewLine
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
```

and I want to do my merge result will be

```
Dim listsample = New List(Of String)

listsample.AddRange(Strings.Split(str + st2 + st3 + " ", " ", -1, CompareMethod.Binary))
```

and I want final result will be

```
listsample.AddRamge(Strings.Split("Sample1:Pass1 Sample2:Pass2 Sample3:Pass3, " ", -1, CompareMethod.Binary))
```

for easy to understand what I'm saying is how can I convert this

```
sam.Text += str + str3 & vbNewLine
```

into this

```
listsample.AddRamge(Strings.Split("Sample1:Pass1 Sample2:Pass2 Sample3:Pass3, " ", -1, CompareMethod.Binary))
```

Comment: It seems you have asked 7 question and not accepted a single answer. That won't provide much help to future readers.

Comment: If `str2 = ""` then `str + str2 + str3 & vbNewLine` and `str + str3 & vbNewLine` are the same, so there is no need for the `If`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq to return ALL pairs of elements from two lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575925/linq-to-return-all-pairs-of-elements-from-two-lists). In VB.NET, that would be `Dim sample = (From a In TextBox3.Lines From b In TextBox2.Lines From c In TextBox1.Lines Select (a & b & c)).ToList()` and then use `tbSam.Lines = sample.ToArray()` to populate the TextBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    Dim sep = TextBox2.Text
    For Each line1 As String In TextBox1.Lines
        For Each line2 As String In TextBox3.Lines
            If Not sep = "" Then
                lst.Add(line1 & sep & line2)
            Else
                lst.Add(line1 & line2 & vbNewLine)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For Each s In lst
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
End Sub
```