# dynamic nested looping

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a list of objects dynamically created.
MyObject is a custom object consisting of List of Items. So for example :

MyObject Instance1 has `{ a, b }`

MyObject Instance2 has `{ x, y, z}`

MyObject Instance3 has `{ 1, 2, 4, 5 }`

...............

..............

MyObject InstanceN has `{ n1, n2 ............}`

I want to be able to use either recursion or an iterative approach to solve the problem of generating all unique combinations.

How do I generate all unique combinations .. an output like this

```
{a, x, 1,......., n1}
{a, x, 1,......., n2}
{a, x, 2,......., n1}
{a, x, 2,......., n2}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), and Eric Lippert has written an [excellent blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/), with sample code for how to do this in LINQ, that you can probably adapt.

You can also [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073713/is-there-a-good-linq-way-to-do-a-cartesian-product), which is similarly related.