# Using LINQ to iterate combinations

Tags: combinations, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating all Possible Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations)
>   [Is there a good LINQ way to do a cartesian product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073713/is-there-a-good-linq-way-to-do-a-cartesian-product)
>   [How to generate combination of N elements with limited supply of 2 each without explicit nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980505/how-to-generate-combination-of-n-elements-with-limited-supply-of-2-each-without)

I have a list of lists, and I want to iterate all the possible combinations where I choose one element from each inner list. This is pretty straightforward if I know at compile-time how many lists there are, but how can I do it when I *don't* know in advance how many lists there will be?

If I have three lists (and if I know, at compile-time, that there will be exactly three lists), and I want all the combinations of choosing a single element from each of the three lists, I can do that easily with a LINQ query:

```
var list1 = new[] { 1, 2 };
var list2 = new[] { 3, 4 };
var list3 = new[] { 5, 6 };
var combinations = from item1 in list1
                   from item2 in list2
                   from item3 in list3
                   select new[] { item1, item2, item3 };
// Results:
// {1, 3, 5}
// {1, 3, 6}
// {1, 4, 5}
// {1, 4, 6}
// {2, 3, 5}
// {2, 3, 6}
// {2, 4, 5}
// {2, 4, 6}
```

But how can I do the same thing when I don't know at compile-time how many lists there will be?

```
var lists = new[] {
    new[] { 1, 2 },
    new[] { 3, 4 },
    new[] { 5, 6 } };
var combinations = ???;

// This particular example happens to be the same inputs as above, so it
// has the same expected outputs. But there could be two lists instead,
// or four, so the three hard-coded "from" clauses won't work.
```

It seems like this should actually be doable in LINQ -- SelectMany already does the equivalent of two nested foreach loops, so all I need to do is do a bunch of SelectMany calls and then combine all the results with another SelectMany. Or something. But when it starts getting meta like that, my brain gets all tied in knots. I can't get a handle on how to put the pieces together. I can't even figure out what the generic type arguments to the outer SelectMany call would be.

How can I iterate those lists of lists, and return all the combinations, without knowing at compile-time how many lists there will be?

(Note: everywhere I used arrays above, I'd be fine with using `IEnumerable<T>` instead. Arrays are easier to write in sample code, but I'm expecting that the output is more likely to be in the form `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` rather than the `int[][]` I show in my sample output above.)

Comment: and here's your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations/3098381#3098381)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of either of those *questions* -- both questions are asking about a fixed number of lists -- but both questions do in fact contain an *answer* (the same person's answer in both cases!) for the variable-number-of-lists case.

Comment: @Steven, the question you linked is newer than mine, so if anything, it's a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use SelectMany to combine the SelectMany calls; you use Aggregate. Code courtesy of [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations/3098381#3098381) (answering on a question that's much more specific than this one, but giving a general answer that fits this question as well):

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) => 
            from accseq in accumulator 
            from item in sequence 
            select accseq.Concat(new[] {item}) :                         
        );
}
```

As with all of Eric's answers, he includes a [detailed discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations/3098381#3098381) that lays out exactly how and why this works, in terms of the equivalent non-LINQ code.