# Custom iteration for multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, customization, iteration

Something like:

```
forelement (element G_Element, Grid)
{
    Grid[G_Element.dim1, G_Element.dim2] = 
        new clsGridElement(G_Element.dim1, G_Element.dim2);
}
```

instead of

```
for (int X = 0; X < GridWidth; X++) 
    for (int Y = 0; Y < GridHeight; Y++) 
        Grid[X, Y] = new clsGridElement(X, Y);
```

If something doesn't innately exist, is that something that could be created?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx); [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) and [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if you're writing your own custom iterators.  In your example, the `for` loop seems simpler, though.

Comment: Check out results of "C# linq Cartesian product" search to construct suitable enumeration. There are couple good posts by the Eric Lippert here like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073713/is-there-a-good-linq-way-to-do-a-cartesian-product and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073713/is-there-a-good-linq-way-to-do-a-cartesian-product and

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this - just make a custom type that exposes these, and use a regular foreach:

```
public class TwoDimensionalIterator
{
    public TwoDimensionalIterator(int i, int j)
    {
       this.Dim1 = i; this.Dim2 = j;
    }
    public int Dim1 { get; private set; }
    public int Dim2 { get; private set; }
}
```

Then make an extension method somewhere to return an enumerable of this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TwoDimensionalIterator> IterateTwoDim<T>(this T[,] array)
{
     for (int i=0;i<array.GetLength(0);++i)
         for (int j=0;i<array.GetLength(1);++j)
            yield return new TwoDimensionalIterator(i,j);
}
```

With this, you could then do:

```
foreach(var index in Grid.IterateTwoDim())
{
    Grid[index.Dim1, index.Dim2] = new clsGridElement(index.Dim1, index.Dim2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do here, or why, or what you expect to get from it, but if you implement your own iterator than implements the [IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) interface then you could create something that would hit every cell in your 2D (or more) collection.

Of course, you won't actually gain anything performance-wise from doing this versus just using nested loops, but I guess it'd be syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

Such creation of indexes can be obtained by using "Cartesian product" of all indexes. Here is sample based on [Is there a good LINQ way to do a cartesian product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073713/is-there-a-good-linq-way-to-do-a-cartesian-product) (courtesy of the Eric Lippert):

```
var allIndexes = from dim1 in Enumerable.Range(0, Grid.GetLength(0))
from dim2 in Enumerable.Range(0, Grid.GetLength(1))
select new {dim1, dim2};

foreach (var G_Element in allIndexes)
{
    Grid[G_Element.dim1, G_Element.dim2] = 
        new clsGridElement(G_Element.dim1, G_Element.dim2);
}
```