# How to combine multiple lists of same or different lengths in Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, join

I would like to build a method or extension method **that takes multiple lists** and combines them in the following way:

Lets say i have two lists:

```
        int[] list1 =  {3, 1, 2};
        int[] list2 =  {5, 4 };
```

I would expect a list of arrays as a result like this:

```
[1,4]
[1,5]
[2,4]
[2,5]
[3,4]
[3,5]
```

The number of columns in my resulting list of arrays would be determined by the amount
of lists passed and both columns need to be sorted.
The number of rows is just the (length of list A) * (length of list B) * (length of list N)

In this example is 3 * 2 = 6 rows. 2 columns (because 2 input lists).

What would be an elegant way of doing this with linq?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you even tried solving this with normal loops and natural algorithm first? I would never use `LINQ` for such a complicated problem. Even when `LINQ` can do that for you, it would be less efficient and more `hard-to-understand` than the normal loops. **LINQ should not be used at any cost**.

Comment: I agree that LINQ may be harder to understand and less efficient some times, but I want to learn more about it. I thought about solving this with normal loops but was curious about the LINQ way. My application won't be dealing with enormous lists so I think performance shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @KingKing: This is a perfectly reasonable problem to solve with LINQ and is not complicated in the least. The 2-ary Cartesian product is in fact the *foundational* LINQ sequence operation, `SelectMany`. All LINQ operators can be built out of `SelectMany`; it is the bind operation of the sequence monad. The n-ary Cartesian product is a bit more complicated of course.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks, maybe you're too familiar with `LINQ`, to me, sometimes I still feel it's easier to think out the solution with traditional loops (and separate methods) than using `LINQ`, however I still always use `LINQ` as partially as possible (not kind of `one-line LINQ`).

Comment: @EricLippert if you post my answer as you I'll be happy to accept yours. I don't want to accept my own answer when credit goes to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try cross join

```
int[] list1 =  {3, 1, 2};
int[] list2 =  {5, 4 }; 

var result = (from l1 in list1
             from l2 in list2
             select new [] {l1, l2}).ToList()
```

Comment: How can I adapt this into a method that can take n amount of lists?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx):

```
var combinations = list1.SelectMany(i1 => list2.Select(i2 => new[] { i1, i2 }));
```

or if you prefer

```
var combinations = list1.SelectMany(i1 => list2, (i1, i2) => new[] { i1, i2 });
```

If you want to get the results in a specific order you can follow this up with `OrderBy` etc.

Comment: But what if I send more than 2 lists? I would like to have a method that can take n amount of lists.

Comment: @AdolfoPerez: That would be more complicated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073713/is-there-a-good-linq-way-to-do-a-cartesian-product

Answer (score 2):

Credit goes here to @Jon for pointing me to the right source and @EricLippert for his clever solution:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct =
          new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
        return sequences.Aggregate(
          emptyProduct,
          (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
    }
```

http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/

Works nice with ints and strings:

```
        string[] list1 =  {"1", "2", "3"};
        string[] list2 =  { "4","5" };

        var lists = new List<string[]>(){list1,list2};

        var result = lists.CartesianProduct();
```