# Is there a linq Function to do a cross point of multiple lists C#

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class CrossPoint
{
    private class Color 
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public Color(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var list1 = new List<Color>() { new Color("Green"), new Color("Black") };
        var list2 = new List<Color>() { new Color("Orange"), new Color("Red") , new Color("Blue") };
        var list3 = new List<Color>() { new Color("Yellow"), new Color("Pink") };
        var CompleteList = new List<List<Color>>();
        CompleteList.Add(list1);
        CompleteList.Add(list2);
        CompleteList.Add(list3);

        var result = Result(CompleteList);
        /*
            Green, Orange, Yellow,
            Green, Orange, Pink,
            Green, Red, Yellow,
            Green, Red,Pink,
            Green, Blue, Yellow,
            Green, Blue, Pink,
            Black, Orange, Yellow,
            Black, Orange, Pink,
            Black, Red, Yellow,
            Black, Red,Pink,
            Black, Blue, Yellow,
            Black, Blue, Pink,
         */
    }

    private Color[,] Result(List<List<Color>> colors) {
        // Do Something
        return new Color[1, 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question, can explain what you are trying to do a bit more.

Comment: im looking for the answer of the DoSomething comment basically how to do a cartesian product i think is called for an N Number of lists with different number of elements in each list

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643382/cartesian-products-with-n-number-of-list/25643434

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't agree with the target; Yash's proposal is better. I've added it, but not removed yours

Comment: @user1742179 I believe you can use yash' proposal with just some minor work to turn it into a 2D array (but.. euww, 2D arrays.. I'd leave it as an `IE<IE<Color>>`

Comment: @CaiusJard - Fair enough. You're right.