# Linq to Object combine 2 arrays in one as one to many

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have 2 lists with next type `IList<string>` and `IList<int>`
For example I have next values in first list

```
AA
BB
CC
```

and in other array

```
1
2
```

I would like to get combined list with next results

```
AA 1
BB 1
CC 1
AA 2
BB 2
CC 2
```

Is it possible to to with LINQ to Object only ?

Comment: what do you want as a result? a list of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the order does not matter, then this:

```
from left in new List<string>{"AA", "BB", "CC"}
from right in new List<string>{"1", "2"}
   select string.Format("{0} {1}", left, right)
```

which outputs:

```
AA 1 
AA 2 
BB 1 
BB 2 
CC 1 
CC 2
```

It's called cartesian product: [Is there a good LINQ way to do a cartesian product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073713/is-there-a-good-linq-way-to-do-a-cartesian-product)

Comment: The above is included in the "MoreLINQ" project: https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Cartesian.cs

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of strings as a result, this should do the trick:

```
var result = numbers
    .SelectMany(x => letters.Select(l => string.Join(" ", l, x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<string> firstList = new List<string>();
   firstList.Add("AA");
   firstList.Add("BB");
   firstList.Add("CC");

   List<int> secondList = new List<int>();
   secondList.Add(1);
   secondList.Add(2);

   var lstFinal = (from f1 in firstList
                   from f2 in secondList
                   select new { f1, f2 }).ToList();
   foreach (var s in lstFinal)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(s.f1 + " " +s.f2);
   }
   Console.Read();
}
```

Output:

```
AA 1 
AA 2 
BB 1 
BB 2 
CC 1 
CC 2
```