# Is it possible to use a single SelectMany to get the following sequence?

Tags: c#

I want to get the following sequence:

[image]

Is it possible to use one `SelectMany` to get such a sequence?

## Minimal Working Example

```
static void Main()
{
    var x = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).Where(n => n % 2 == 1);
    var y = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).Where(n => n % 2 == 0);
    var z = x.SelectMany(m => y, (m, n) => new int[] { m, n }).SelectMany(o => o);
    foreach (int n in z)
        Console.Write($"{n},");
    Console.WriteLine("\b.");
}
```

Comment: This code will produce your desired result. Why do you want to have only one `SelectMany`?

Comment: Your code is fairly unreadable as it is (I can't for the life of me work out what sequence you are generating). I would imagine if you do cram it into a one liner then it will become even harder to understand what it is doing...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the same result"? You look like you are creating a cartesian product of two sets and then flattening them into a single string. Do you actually want the m,n pairs or do you want the string?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity: No need to be snippy. Getting a cartesian product of two sets of numbers is a much more common thing to want to do than to then flatten that set into a single list of integers. It also wasn't clear if printing to console was the result you wanted or whether generating z was the end result. I'm assuming z (which in the spirit of being snippy I will note is not an array of numbers) and have answered accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is a cartesian product and then flattening it. It can be done quite nicely in a few other ways:

```
var z = from m in x
from n in y
from t in new []{m,n}
select t;
```

Which is probably the nicest looking

```
var z = x.Join(y, _=>1, _=>1, (m,n)=>new int[] { m, n }).SelectMany(o => o);
```

This is closer to your original but substitutes your first SelectMany with a join. The key selectors are both `_=>1` because you want the cartesian product which this will give you.

Comment: I think this snippy answer conforms to my requirement "single `SelectMany`". :-)

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity: I've just come across some comments from Eric Lippert on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073724/338068 which suggests that SelectMany is much better to use than Join for this sort of thing which means that probably performance-wise my suggestions are inferior to your original code. Though of course it is quite possible that performance isn't something you are worried about if your data sets aren't that big (I'm assuming the question here is a trimmed down version of what you are actually doing with real data).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var z = x.SelectMany(m => y, (m, n) => new { m, n }).Select(k => Tuple.Create(k.m, k.n));
```

Or even simpler with new C# 7.0 feature value tuple:

```
var z = x.SelectMany(m => y, (m, n) => new { m, n }).Select(k => (k.m, k.n));
```

Comment: Will z not then be an IEnumerable of Tuples rather than an IEnumerable of ints as desired? Or is there more magic  to tuples than I am aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Despite your requires, for the sake of code clearness I suggest you just to use nested loops, e.g.

```
IEnumerable<int> DummySequence(int n)
{
    var odd = Enumerable.Range(1, n).Where(x => x % 2 == 1);
    var even = Enumerable.Range(1, n).Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToArray();

    foreach (var oddNumber in odd)
    {
        foreach (var evenNumber in even)
        {
            yield return oddNumber;
            yield return evenNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you used just one `ToArray()`?

Comment: Yes. I enumerate odd numbers only once, so don't need `ToArray()` there. But even numbers could be enumerated several times, so I used `ToArray()` for performance reasons.