# Cartesian product of an array with itself a variable amount of times?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, linq, cartesian-product

I want to write a function which returns the cartesian product of an array with itself a variable amount of times.

Now, if the number of cartesian products is known at compile time, then I can do the following  (for 3 cartesian products):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numSet = {1,2,3,4};
                        
            var cartesianProduct = from letter in numSet
                                   from number in numSet
                                   from colour in numSet
                                   select new { num1, num2, num3};
        }
```

Now, I have seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073806/5859885, which seems to provide a method for dealing with a variable amount of sets. The method is as follows:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
        {
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
            return sequences.Aggregate(
                emptyProduct,
                (accumulator, sequence) =>
                from accseq in accumulator
                from item in sequence
                select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
        }
```

Now, I've applied this to my problem as follows (this is for 4 cartesian products (see the for loop), but can easily be wrapped in a method for a variable amount of cartesian products))

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] numSet= new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4};
            List<int[]> numList = new List<int[]>();
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            {
                numList.Add(numSet);
            }

            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> combArray = CartesianProduct(numList);
            foreach(var combo in combArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(combo);
            }

        }
```

Now, this compiles, but I just get the following output for each iteration of the for loop (instead of the cartesian product).
`System.Linq.Enumerable+ConcatNIterator'1[System.Int32]`.

What is happening here?

Comment: Change write statement :  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",combo));

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can store each combination inside an array and then store all of these combos inside a single array? So I have a jagged array (array of arrays)?

Comment: They are already in the variable numList.  It is not jagged, just a regular two dimensional array since the width is always 4.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the method to return each combination as an array:

```
static IEnumerable<T[]> CartesianProduct<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) {
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
        from accseq in accumulator
        from item in sequence
        select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }).ToArray());
}
```

Then convert the final return into an array of arrays:

```
var combArray = CartesianProduct(numList).ToArray();
```

NOTE: In general, it is more efficient to use a `List<int>` instead of an `int[]` when building dynamically, also depending on how you are processing the answer, the `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` may be a better form, or the `IEnumerable<int[]>` rather than an array of arrays.