# N-wise combinations of elements from different lists

Tags: c#, .net

I have a certain number (m) of lists of variable length (the lists don't have always the same length), for example m=4

```
List1: {1,2,3,4,5}
List2: {6,7}
List3: {8,9,10}
List4: {11,12,13,14,15,16}
```

I would like to realize a method like this:

```
method(list1, list2, list3, list4, n)
```

where `n` is the n-wise combinations to take.

For example n=2 all pairs, n=3 all triples.. as we can do with NUnit.

Is there a method like this in the framework?

All lists are strings lists

Thanks.

Comment: NUnit is open source, and is sourced under the MIT license. If you want a piece of MIT, go and take it. The code seems to be here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/Builders/CombinatorialStrategy.cs

Comment: do numbers from different lists make a pair or a pair is just a pair of 2 lists? It is not clear

Comment: the question is unclear, what does the variable m is needed? and which number should you take to the new list?

Comment: It is the approach used in combinatorial testing, as described here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing
N-wise testing with variable taking values from m different lists. I don't know how to explain this better
N=2 means all possible couples of elements from the m different lists, N=3 all possibile triples etc.

Comment: how do you want to form pairs from 4 lists?

Comment: Do searches for "n-Ary Cartesian Product". Eric Lippert has some [great examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073806/2330053).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your `method(list1, list2, list3, list4, n)`, you're looking for the [params keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)