# How do I produce a full set of combinations with string manipulation?

Tags: c#, string, combinations

I have a small project where I have an input sentence where it is possible for the user to specify variations:

```
The {small|big} car is {red|blue}
```

Above is a sample sentence i want to split into 4 sentences, like this:

- The small car is red
- The big car is red
- The small car is blue
- The big car is blue

I can't seem to wrap my mind around the problem. Maybe someone can helt me pls.

**Edit**
Here is my initial code

```
Regex regex = new Regex("{(.*?)}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text);
string data = richTextBox1.Text;

//build amount of variations
foreach (Match match in collection)
{
    string[] alternatives = match.Value.Split(new char[] { '|', '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string alternative in alternatives)
    {
        //here i get problems                  
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? ([hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx))

Comment: Nope, not missed a homework tag :-)

Comment: Your task is a greatly simplified version of generating all the strings of a context-free language. If this subject interests you, see my blog series on that topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/grammars/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need a dynamic cartesian function for this. Eric Lippert's [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) written in response to [Generating all Possible Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3093622/102112).

Firstly, we need to parse the input string:

```
Regex ex = new Regex(@"(?<=\{)(?<words>\w+(\|\w+)*)(?=\})");
var sentence = "The {small|big} car is {red|blue}";
```

then the input string should be modified to be used in `string.Format`-like functions:

```
int matchCount = 0;
var pattern = ex.Replace(sentence, me => 
{
    return (matchCount++).ToString(); 
});
// pattern now contains "The {0} car is {1}"
```

then we need to find all the matches and to apply Eric's excellent `CartesianProduct` extension method:

```
var set = ex.Matches(sentence)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => 
        m.Groups["words"].Value
            .Split('|')
    ).CartesianProduct();

foreach (var item in set)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pattern, item.ToArray());
}
```

this will produce:

```
The small car is red
The small car is blue
The big car is red
The big car is blue
```

and, finally, the `CartesianProduct` method (taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx)):

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) =>  
      from accseq in accumulator  
      from item in sequence  
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item}));                
}
```

Comment: Wow.  I think I'm getting good at c#, then I see answers like that remind me I've got plenty left to learn.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     private void ExpandString( List<string> result, string text )
>     {
>       var start = text.IndexOf('{');
>       var end = text.IndexOf('}');
>       if (start >= 0 && end > start)
>       {
>           var head = text.Substring(0, start);
>           var list = text.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1).Split('|');
>           var tail = text.Substring(end + 1);
>           foreach (var item in list)
>               ExpandString(result, head + item + tail);
>       }
>       else
>           result.Add(text);
>     }
> ```

Use like:

```
    var result = new List<string>();
    ExpandString(result, "The {small|big} car is {red|blue}");
```

Comment: This fails when { is the first character of the sentince!
changing "if (start > 0"  to ">=" fixes the problem

Comment: Ooh ooh pick me! :-)  Mine will work for that case, but still isn't going to be smart enough to figure out un-matched { characters (which I think would be a bit more complex)

Comment: @Drew: What do you mean by "unmatched { characters"?

Comment: I mean if you wanted a { or } character to actually show up in the output string, instead of just breaking the parser.  I just brought it up to say that we're all coming up with relatively simple parsers that get the job done for the example input - but they're not going to be a robust solution that can gracefully deal with all possible inputs.

Comment: @Drew: To counter this you'll have to do something like: Count the amount of { untill you reach a }, also you have to be sure there's the same amount of { as } in the string. If not it will fail somewhere because the program doesn't know which of the { it can skip or not.
When you know how much { you have before the first} you can skip the }'s until you reach the same amount and so on.
Hope you understand what I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the number of variations, recursion is your friend:

```
static public IEnumerable<string> permute(string template)
{
    List<string> options;
    string before;
    string after;
    if (FindFirstOptionList(template, out options, out before, out after))
    {
        foreach (string option in options)
        {
            foreach (string permutation in permute(before + option + after))
            {
                yield return permutation;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        yield return template;
    }
}

static public bool FindFirstOptionList(string template, out List<string> options, out string before, out string after)
{
    before = string.Empty;
    after = string.Empty;
    options = new List<string>(0);
    if (template.IndexOf('{') == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    before = template.Substring(0, template.IndexOf('{'));
    template = template.Substring(template.IndexOf('{') + 1);
    if (template.IndexOf('}') == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    after = template.Substring(template.IndexOf('}') + 1);
    options = template.Substring(0, template.IndexOf('}')).Split('|').ToList();
    return true;
}
```

use is similar to danbystrom's solution, except this one returns an IEnumerable instead of manipulating one of the calling parameters.  Beware syntax errors, etc

```
static void main()
{
    foreach(string permutation in permute("The {small|big} car is {red|blue}"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(permutation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to split the input text into an ordered list of static and dynamic parts. Each dynamic part itself contains a list that stores its values and an index that represents the currently selected value. This index is intially set to zero.

To print out all possible combinations you at first have to implement a method that prints the complete list using the currently set indices of the dynamic parts. For the first call all indices will be set to zero.

Now you can increment the index of the first dynamic part and print the complete list. This will give you the first variation. Repeat this until you printed all possible values of the remaining dynamic parts.

Comment: Off topic: This will be a good exercise for my class in C-programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider nesting iterative loops. Something like...

```
foreach(string s in someStringSet)
{
    foreach(string t in someOtherStringSet)
    {
        // do something with s and t
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for this:
Edited version

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var thisstring = "The {Small|Big} car is {Red|Blue}";           
    string FirstString = thisstring.Substring(thisstring.IndexOf("{"), (thisstring.IndexOf("}") - thisstring.IndexOf("{")) + 1);
    string[] FirstPossibility = FirstString.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Split('|');
    thisstring = thisstring.Replace(FirstString, "[0]");
    string SecondString = thisstring.Substring(thisstring.IndexOf("{"), (thisstring.IndexOf("}") - thisstring.IndexOf("{")) + 1);
    string[] SecondPosibility = SecondString.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Split('|');
    thisstring = thisstring.Replace(SecondString, "{1}").Replace("[0]", "{0}");
    foreach (string tempFirst in FirstPossibility)
    {
        foreach (string tempSecond in SecondPosibility)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(thisstring, tempFirst, tempSecond));
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
private void Do()
{
    string str = "The {small|big} car is {red|blue}";

    Regex regex = new Regex("{(.*?)}", RegexOptions.Singleline);

    int i = 0;
    var strWithPlaceHolders = regex.Replace(str, m => "{" + (i++).ToString() + "}");

    var collection = regex.Matches(str);

    var alternatives = collection.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value.Split(new char[] { '|', '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    var replacers = GetReplacers(alternatives);

    var combinations = new List<string>();
    foreach (var replacer in replacers)
    {
        combinations.Add(string.Format(strWithPlaceHolders, replacer));
    }
}

private IEnumerable<object[]> GetReplacers(IEnumerable<string[]> alternatives)
{
    return GetAllPossibilities(0, alternatives.ToList());
}

private IEnumerable<object[]> GetAllPossibilities(int level, List<string[]> list)
{
    if (level == list.Count - 1)
    {
        foreach (var elem in list[level])
            yield return new[] { elem };
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var elem in list[level])
        {
            var thisElemAsArray = new object[] { elem };
            foreach (var subPossibilities in GetAllPossibilities(level + 1, list))
                yield return thisElemAsArray.Concat(subPossibilities).ToArray();
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string color = SomeMethodToGetColor();
string size = SomeMethodToGetSize();

string sentence = string.Format("The {0} car is {1}", size, color);
```

Comment: I dont see this solution? There is not a specific amount of variations specified in my sentence, it could be none or it could be several.

Comment: The question has 4 sentences. The only options are for size and color. I may have mis-interpreted your question. Are you saying the user inputs the complete sentence with free-form text? i.e., a TextBox to enter the entire sentence?

Comment: No offense, but this is not helpful at all. H4mm3rHead wants to determine all possible combinations.