# how can i get combinations of string Array?

Tags: c#, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating all Possible Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations)

I'm trying to do a little algorithm in C++ or C#

Basically if you have an array:

```
{"ab","cd"}
```

output:

```
ac
ad
bc
bd
```

(I have two nested for loops)

but what if i have an array of 3 elements? or 4 ?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: Try to write to console all binary numbers with two (or three, or N) digits, and see how you can apply it to this problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to vary the number of "nested loops" you need to use recursion.

```
void printCombination(string[] str, string partial, int p) {
    if (p == str.Length) {
        Console.WriteLine(partial);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i != str[p].Length; i++) {
        printCombination(str, partial + str[p][i], p+1);
    }
}
```

Initial call looks like this:

```
printCombination(new[] {"ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"}, "", 0);
```

**EDIT** (in response to a comment by OP)

To understand what is going on, you need to understand the meaning of the parameters first:

- `str` is the array of strings. Each element of the array corresponds to a nesting level of the imaginary nested loops: element 0 is for the outer loop, element 1 is for the first level of nesting, and so on.
- `partial` is the partially constructed result string. It is empty at the initial level, has one character at the first level of nesting, two at the second, and so on.
- `p` is the nesting level. It is zero in the initial level, one at the first nesting level, and so on.

The function has two parts - the stopping condition, and the body of the recursive call. The stopping condition is simple: once we get to the last level, `partial` result is no longer "partial": it is complete; we can print it out and exit. How do we know that we're at the last level? The number of elements of `str` equals the number of levels, so when `p` equals the length of the `str` array, we're done.

The body of the recursive call is a loop. It does the same thing that your nested loops do, but for only one level: each iteration adds one letter from its own array, and calls itself recursively for the next level.

The best way to see this in action is to set a breakpoint on the line with the `return` statement, and look at the call stack window . Click each invocation level, and inspect the values of function parameters.

If you are up for an exercise, try modifying this function to take two parameters instead of three. Hint: you can eliminate the last parameter by observing that the length of `partial` always matches the value of `p`.

Comment: "need to use" is not quite true, since any recursive algorithm could be written iteratively.  However, recursion is easiest to grasp.

Comment: @Hogan Well, logically recursive algorithm remains recursive no matter how it is implemented. In the end, it all boils down to using a stack, either a hardware or a software one.

Comment: worked like a charm!!
Thank you dasblinkenlight :)

Comment: Isn't this example tail end recursive so a stack is not needed?

Comment: @Hogan This is not a tail call because it is in a loop.

Comment: done..dasblinkenlight you are my savior :) i've always been sloppy at recursion,dynamic algorithms and such..

if its okay, can you walk through me what you did? how you approached it? :)

Comment: @SalmaNafady Sure, I just edited the answer. Try the little exercise at the end to make sure that you've understood the explanation completely.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the Cartesian product of arbitrarily many sequences of characters. See this blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

and this StackOverflow question, which you have duplicated.

[Generating all Possible Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations)

Answer (score 0):

in c++ there is an algorithm called `std::next_permutation`. Here is an example, hope this helps you.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string s = "aba";
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    do {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    } while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
}
```

---

```
Output:
aab
aba
baa
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you cannot use nested for loops, since you cannot vary this programmatically.

In that case, use a counter for each element, which is the current element you are iterating.
Use a while loop and a function to check if you are finished.

Increase the counter of the first element, if it has reached its maximum, set it to 0 and increase the next counter etc.

(edit: the solution using the permutation probably makes use of my solution internally).