# Sql Server Service Broker - thorough, in-use example of externally activated console app

Tags: sql-server, sample, service-broker, activation

I need some guidance from anyone who has deployed a real-world, in-production application that uses the Sql Server Service Broker external activation mechanism (via the Service Broker External Activator from the Feature Pack).

### Current mindset:

My specs are rather simple (or at least I think so), so I'm thinking of the following basic flow:

1. order-like entity gets inserted into a *Table_Orders* with state "confirmed"
2. *SP_BeginOrder* gets executed and does the following:

   - begins a TRANSACTION
   - starts a DIALOG from *Service_HandleOrderState* to *Service_PreprocessOrder*
   - stores the conversation handle (from now on *PreprocessingHandle*) in a specific column of the *Orders* table
   - sends a MESSAGE of type *Message_PreprocessOrder* containing the order id using *PreprocessingHandle*
   - ends the TRANSACTION

   *Note that I'm not ending the conversation, I don't want ["fire-and-forget"](http://rusanu.com/2006/04/06/fire-and-forget-good-for-the-military-but-not-for-service-broker-conversations/)*
3. event notification on *Queue_PreprocessOrder* activates an instance of *PreprocessOrder.exe* (max concurrent of 1) which does the following:

   - begins a SqlTransaction
   - receives top 1 MESSAGE from *Queue_PreprocessOrder*
   - if message type is *Message_PreprocessOrder* (format XML):

     - sets the order state to "preprocessing" in *Table_Orders* using the order id in the message body
     - loads n collections of data of which computes an [n-ary Carthesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098381/720616%20n-ary%20Carthesian%20product) (via Linq, AFAIK this is not possible in T-SQL) to determine the order items collection
     - inserts the order items rows into a *Table_OrderItems*
     - sends a MESSAGE of type *Message_PreprocessingDone*, containing the same order id, using *PreprocessingHandle*
     - ends the conversation pertaining to *PreprocessingHandle*
   - commits the SqlTransaction
   - exits with Environment.Exit(0)
4. internal activation on *Queue_HandleOrderState* executes a SP (max concurrent of 1) that:

   - begins a TRANSACTION
   - receives top 1 MESSAGE from *Queue_InitiatePreprocessOrder*
   - if message type is *Message_PreprocessingDone*:

     - sets the order state to "processing" in *Table_Orders* using the order id in the message body
     - starts a DIALOG from *Service_HandleOrderState* to *Service_ProcessOrderItem*
     - stores the conversation handle (from now on *ProcessOrderItemsHandle*) in a specific column of *Table_Orders*
     - creates a cursor for rows in *Table_OrderItems* for current order id and for each row:

       - sends a MESSAGE of type *Message_ProcessOrderItem*, containing the order item id, using *ProcessOrderItemsHandle*
   - if message type is *Message_ProcessingDone*:

     - sets the order state to "processed" in *Table_Orders* using the order id in the message body
   - if message type is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog` (END DIALOG):

     - ends the conversation pertaining to conversation handle of the message
   - ends the TRANSACTION
5. event notification on *Queue_ProcessOrderItem* activates an instance of *ProcessOrderItem.exe* (max concurrent of 1) which does the following:

   - begins a SqlTransaction
   - receives top 1 MESSAGE from *Queue_ProcessOrderItem*
   - if message type is *Message_ProcessOrderItem* (format XML):

     - sets the order item state to "processing" in *Table_OrdersItems* using the order item id in the message body, then:

       - loads a collection of order item parameters
       - makes a HttpRequest to a URL using the parameters
       - stores the HttpResponse as a PDF on filesystem
     - if any errors occurred in above substeps, sets the order item state to "error", otherwise "ok"
     - performs a lookup in the *Table_OrdersItems* to determine if all order items are processed (state is "ok" or "error")
     - if all order items are processed:

       - sends a MESSAGE of type *Message_ProcessingDone*, containing the order id, using *ProcessOrderItemsHandle*
       - ends the conversation pertaining to *ProcessOrderItemsHandle*
   - commits the SqlTransaction
   - exits with Environment.Exit(0)

### Notes:

- specs specify MSSQL compatibility 2005 through 2012, so:

  - no CONVERSATION GROUPS
  - no CONVERSATION PRIORITY
  - no POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING ( STATUS = OFF )
- I am striving to achieve overall flow integrity and continuity, not speed
- given that tables and SPs reside in *DB1* whilst Service Broker objects (messages, contracts, queues, services) reside in *DB2*, *DB2* is SET TRUSTWORTHY

### Questions:

1. Are there any major design flaws in the described architecture ?
2. Order completion state tracking doesn't seem right. Is there a better method ? Maybe using QUEUE RETENTION ?
3. My intuition tells me that in no case whatsoever should the activated external exe terminate with an exit code other than 0, so there should be `try{..}catch(Exception e){..} finally{ Environment.Exit(0) }` in Main. Is this assumption correct ?
4. How would you organize error handling in DB code ? Is an error log table enough?
5. How would you organize error handling in external exe C# code ? Same error logging 
   table ?
6. I've seen the [SQL Server Service Broker Product Samples](http://msftsbprodsamples.codeplex.com/), but the Service Broker Interface seems overkill for my seemingly simpler case. Any alternatives for a simpler Service Broker object model ?
7. Any cross-version "portable" admin tool for Service Broker capable of at least draining poison messages ?
8. Have you any decent code samples for any of the above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q: Are there any major design flaws in the described architecture ?**
A: Couple of minor perks:
 - waiting for an HTTP request to complete while holding open a transaction is bad. You can't achieve transactional consistency between a database and HTTP anyway, so don't risk to have a transaction stretch for minutes when the HTTP is slow. The typical pattern is to {begin tran/receive/[begin conversation timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx)/commit} then issue the HTTP call w/o any DB xact. If the HTTP call succeeds then {begin xact/send response/end conversation/commit}. If the HTTP fails (or client crashes) then let the conversation time activate you again. You'll get a timer message (no body), you need to pick up the item id associated with the handle from your table(s).

**Q: Order completion state tracking doesn't seem right. Is there a better method ? Maybe using QUEUE RETENTION ?**
A: My one critique of your state tracking is the dependency on scanning the order items to determine that the current processed one is the last one (5.3.4). For example you could add the information that this is the 'last' item to be processed in the item state so you know, when processing it, that you need to report the completion. RETENTION is only useful in debugging or when you have logic that require to run 'logical rollback' and to compensating actions on conversation error.

**Q: My intuition tells me that in no case whatsoever should the activated external exe terminate with an exit code other than 0, so there should be try{..}catch(Exception e){..} finally{ Environment.Exit(0) } in Main. Is this assumption correct ?**
A: The most important thing is for the activated process to issue a RECEIVE statement on the queue. If it fails to do so the queue monitor [may enter the notified state forever](http://rusanu.com/2008/08/03/understanding-queue-monitors/). Exit code is, if I remember correctly, irrelevant. As with any background process is important to catch and log exceptions, otherwise you'll never even know it has a problem when it start failing. In addition to disciplined try/catch blocks, Hookup [`Application.ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) for UI apps and [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) for both UI and non-UI apps.

**Q: How would you organize error handling in DB code ? Is an error log table enough?**
A: I will follow up later on this. Error log table is sufficient imho.

**Q: How would you organize error handling in external exe C# code ? Same error logging table ?**
A: I created [bugcollect.com](http://bugcollect.com) exactly because I had to handle such problems with my own apps. The problem is more than logging, you also want *some* aggregation and analysis (at least detect duplicate reports) and suppress floods of errors from some deployment config mishap 'on the field'.  Truth be told nowadays there are more options, eg. [exceptron.com](https://www.exceptron.com/). And of course I think FogBugs also has logging capabilities.

**Q: I've seen the SQL Server Service Broker Product Samples, but the Service Broker Interface seems overkill for my seemingly simpler case. Any alternatives for a simpler Service Broker object model ?**
finally, an easy question: Yes, it is overkill. There is no simple model.

**Q: Any cross-version "portable" admin tool for Service Broker capable of at least draining poison messages ?**
A: The problem with poison messages is that the definition of poison message changes with your code: [the poison message is whatever message breaks the current guards set in place to detect it](http://philosophy.thecastsite.com/readings/geb/hofstadter1.html).

**Q: Have you any decent code samples for any of the above ?**
A: No

One more point: try to avoid any reference from DB1 to DB2 (eg. 4.3.4 is activated in DB1 and reads the items table from DB2). This creates cross DB dependencies which break when a) one DB is offline (eg. for maintenance) or overloaded or b) you add database mirroring for HA/DR and one DB fails over. Try to make the code to work even if DB1 and DB2 are on different machines (and no linked servers). If necessary, add more info to the messages payload. And if you architect it that way that DB2 *can* be on a different machine and even multiple DB2 machines can exists to scale out the HTTP/PDF writing work.

And finally: this design will be *very* slow. I'm talking low tens messages per second slow, with so many dialogs/messages involved and everything with max_queue_readers 1. This may or may not be acceptable for you.

Comment: **Q1:**
So when _ProcessOrderItem.exe_ receives a DialogTimer message, it must ALWAYS do a BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER, then retry the HTTP request?

Comment: **Q2**: You suggest setting a "IsLastItem" flag on the order items.
Wouldn't this conflict with the _DialogTimer_ messages, as _ProcessOrderItem.exe_ would reach the last order item and set the order state to "processed" BEFORE receiving the _DialogTimer_ messages?

Comment: **Q7**: I was referring to something along the lines of the [SSB Admin Tool](http://sqlsrvsrvcbrkr.codeplex.com/releases/view/3853). I can't find source for it so can't modify for cross-verson compat

Comment: Q1: yes, always schedule the retry, commit, then do the work. This is 100% failsafe, leaves no race condition where the system can be left w/o a retry timer scheduled. You may consider fancy stuff like exponential backoff and total time limit (eg. give up if every retry failed after 1 day), but simple does not necessarily means bad ;)