# Permutations/Combinations of bounded numbers in C#

Tags: c#, permutation, n-dimensional

Here's something which has been bugging me for the past two days.
I need to populate an initial configuration(/state)-space for a fixpoint algorithm.

In this statespace, each transition weight has a vector of weights, and different bounds may apply to each of the weights in this vector.

This is currently defined as an example transition weight being for example (5,-1,-1)

The bounds for each weight correspond to the index of the weight vector itself, for example the upper bounds for these weights, assuming the lower bound is 0 for all is given by (5,3,3)

Now, to set up the initial configuration space, i need to have every combination of weights available in the beginning. 
(0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,1,0) (1,0,0)... and so on, each of them going to their max bounds.

Now, if i was dealing with a 3-weighted system this would be trivial, but i need to support n-dimensional vectors in my code.

So, any ideas as to how i would accomplish populating this configuration space? (I'm using C# currently)

Comment: See [generating all possible combinations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations). Your version is simpler since you don't care about the letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code for generating all ntuples [implemented in Javascript](http://pastebin.com/Wp50xuxW). It's self-explanatory, but if you need further explanation, I'd be glad to help (I actually tried to write the algorithm in pseudocode but what I wrote ended up looking like the comments)

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a look!
A quick question though - segments.length is referenced in the code, but segments is never declared?

Comment: I copied the code above from a project of mine and there `boundingVector` was named `segments`. I wanted to rename it to make things clearer but guess I missed that part. I'll edit it right away.

Comment: After a quick C# implementation, i am just getting 96 identical tuples. Will investigate further later.

Comment: Nevermind, in my haste i fudged my print method!
This looks promising, i will have to study it a bit more to have a firm grasp of what's going on!
Thanks so much!

Comment: Just run in it in your browser's console to see how it works :)