# How can I make a new set of dictionaries containing all the possible combinations from a dictionary with list as value

Tags: c#, dictionary, combinations

I need to take a dictionary with a string key and a list of strings as value and find all combinations that it can make.
For example:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    {"X", new List<string> {"x", "y", "z"}},
    {"Y", new List<string> {"x", "y"}},
    {"Z", new List<string> {"a", "b"}}
};
```

Will translate to:

```
{X: x, Y: x, Z: a}
{X: x, Y: x, Z: b}
{X: x, Y: y, Z: a}
{X: x, Y: y, Z: b}
{X: y, Y: x, Z: a}
{X: y, Y: x, Z: b}
{X: y, Y: y, Z: a}
{X: y, Y: y, Z: b}
{X: z, Y: x, Z: a}
{X: z, Y: x, Z: b}
{X: z, Y: y, Z: a}
{X: z, Y: y, Z: b}
```

How can I do this the smartest way?

Comment: Are you required to use Dictionaries?

Comment: Do you know permutation?

Comment: use a cross join in a sql server

Comment: What have to tried so far that wasn't successful? Or how do you think this could be accomplished?

Comment: what you are looking for is called a "Cartesian Product"

Comment: This question might help: [Generating all Possible Combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3093622/10263)

Answer (score 7):

How about doing it like this?

```
var combinations =
    from x in myDictionary["X"]
    from y in myDictionary["Y"]
    from z in myDictionary["Z"]
    select new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "X", x },
        { "Y", y },
        { "Z", z },
    };
```

I get this result:

[image: combinations]

---

After some further thought here is a method to compute with any number of elements in the dictionary (i.e. not just "X", "Y", & "Z".)

```
Func<
    Dictionary<string, string>,
    Dictionary<string, string>,
    Dictionary<string, string>> merge = (d1, d2) =>
{
    var d = new Dictionary<string, string>(d1);
    foreach (var kv in d2)
    {
        d.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
    }
    return d;
};

var combinations =
    myDictionary
        .Select(x =>
            x.Value.Select(v =>
                new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { x.Key, v }
                }))
        .Aggregate((xs, vs) =>
            from x in xs
            from v in vs
            select merge(x, v));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your specific example. Hopefully this gives you a start, and it shouldn't be too hard to make it work for a more general approach:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    {"X", new List<string> {"x", "y", "z"}},
    {"Y", new List<string> {"x", "y"}},
    {"Z", new List<string> {"a", "b"}}
};

var combiDicts = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
foreach (var entryXItem in dict["X"])
{
    foreach (var entryYItem in dict["Y"])
    {
        foreach (var entryZItem in dict["Z"])
        {
            combiDicts.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"X", entryXItem}, {"Y", entryYItem}, {"Z", entryZItem}
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
foreach (var d in combiDicts)
    Console.WriteLine("{{X: {0}, Y: {1}, Z: {2}}}", d["X"], d["Y"], d["Z"]);
```

Output:

```
{X: x, Y: x, Z: a}
{X: x, Y: x, Z: b}
{X: x, Y: y, Z: a}
{X: x, Y: y, Z: b}
{X: y, Y: x, Z: a}
{X: y, Y: x, Z: b}
{X: y, Y: y, Z: a}
{X: y, Y: y, Z: b}
{X: z, Y: x, Z: a}
{X: z, Y: x, Z: b}
{X: z, Y: y, Z: a}
{X: z, Y: y, Z: b}
```

Comment: I think the output needs to be a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` (which would not be hard to convert your answer in to)

Comment: From the syntax of the examples in the original unupdated question it looks like he was expecting dictionaries in to dictionaries out.

Comment: @RufusL: look at the title: _"How can I make a new set of dictionaries"_. However, it should be simple, every dictionary contains one x-key/value, one y-key/value and one z-key/value.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what he's looking for, then. In his output, there is no unique key for any of the lines...you need to combine x, y, and z to get a unique key for each line. And when you get that key, what would be the value?

Comment: @RufusL: you could add this: `combiDicts.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            {"X", entryXItem}, {"Y", entryYItem}, {"Z", entryZItem}
                        });` +1 even if it could contain repetitions

Comment: please feel free to edit my answer (or duplicate it as your own and i'll delete mine). I don't understand what a KeyValuePair item would look like in the resulting dictionary.