# c# dynamic linq query at runtime on datset

Tags: linq

I need your help for a small problem. I would like to make the following LINQ query dynamic (at runtime) because I don´t know how many tables there will be in the database (the tablenames are known while runtime).

```
var query = from row1 in ds.Tables["tab1"].AsEnumerable()
        from row2 in ds.Tables["tab2"].AsEnumerable()
        from row3 in ds.Tables["tab3"].AsEnumerable()
        select new { row1, row2, row3 };
```

Is this possible at generate a dynamic LINQ query in this case and write the result to a datatable or array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want a cartesian product of all tables rows?

Comment: Yes Tim that´s what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098381/284240) can create a cartesian product of all tables rows in a `DataSet`.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
        return sequences.Aggregate(
            emptyProduct,
            (accumulator, sequence) =>
                from accseq in accumulator
                from item in sequence
                select accseq.Concat(new[] { item })
            );
    } 
}
```

Now you can use it in this way:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DataRow>> allTablesRows = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>()
    .Select(table => table.AsEnumerable())
    .CartesianProduct();
```

Output:

```
foreach (var x in allTablesRows)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("table:{0} fields:{1}", 
            row.Table.TableName, 
            string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: Impressive! THANK YOU VERY MUCH TIM!

Comment: Just one more question: I had a small error in reasoning :-) Every table has an ID as the first column. I only need to multiply those rows/tables which have the same ID at the beginning... Is it possible to add a "where" statement?

Comment: Maybe it would help to provide a small example n your question. Or - since the question changes - ask another. Do you want to join the rows with the same ID or do you want a cartesian product of all rows where the id appears in another table? It's getting more and more unclear

Comment: I do not need to build a cartesian product of all rows that was my missunderstanding, sorry! I need to have all rows joined on the same id and this must be done for all id´s. I hope it´s getting clearer now.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to add a where condition (parameter) to the "CartesianProduct) Method?

Comment: @derchrome: ask another question with meaningful sample data. It's still not clear what you want as result or what should happen if one ID appears in one table, another in two tables and a third ID appears in five tables. Must an ID appear in all tables? Is the column-name always the same, what's the typeof the column. As i've said, ask a different questions and provide a meaningful sample, a desired result and something that you've tried. Then people are willing to help. I'm currently busy, but you could add a link to that question here if you want.

Comment: Good morning Tim, thank you very much for your time. The new question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263948/dynamic-linq-where-query-with-joining-other-tables