# Create dynamic foreach loop for sequential search type in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, foreach

First analyze my C# code.

```
        string[] shape = { "Round", "Square" };
        string[] Size = { "7", "9", "10" };
        string[] type = { "Chocklate", "Honey", "Vanila" };
        string[] top = { "Blank Cake", "Licenced Image Cake", "Personal Image Cake" };
        string[] msg = { "Happy Birthday", "Own Message", "Get Well Soon" };

        List<string> MyPatterns = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < shape.Length; i++)
        {
            MyPatterns.Add(shape[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < Size.Length; j++)
            {
                MyPatterns.Add(shape[i] + " - " + Size[j]);
                for (int k = 0; k < type.Length; k++)
                {

                    string A = shape[i] + " - " + Size[j] + " - " + type[k];
                    MyPatterns.Add(A);

                    for (int l = 0; l < top.Length; l++)
                    {
                        string B = shape[i] + " - " + Size[j] + " - " + type[k] + " - " + top[l];
                        MyPatterns.Add(B);

                        for (int m = 0; m < msg.Length; m++)
                        {
                            string C = shape[i] + " - " + Size[j] + " - " + type[k] + " - " + top[l] + " - " + msg[m];
                            MyPatterns.Add(C);

                        }

                    }

                }


            }
        }
```

Now above example has 5 static arrays shape, size, type, top, msg and above code shows every combination is possible between these arrays.  Like
Round
Round - 7
Round - 7 - Chocklate  like this all possible combination.

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Currently I have static arrays shape, size, type, etc.. So I am manually writing foreach loop for each array inside upper array.

Now suppose these arrays comes dynamically. I Don't know count the will be for example sometimes it must be shape and size some time its must be shape, size and type, and sometime they are completely different.

So how can I dynamically Generates foreach loop for dynamic arrays ?

Comment: If I get this correctly, you are expecting a List<List<string>> as an input parameter. and you want to produce same result.. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Also you can check this http://linqsamples.com/linq-to-objects/projection/SelectMany-lambda-csharp

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/3098381/88656

Answer (score 2):

Group those dynamic arrays into an array, so you have an array of arrays (AKA [Jagged Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). This way you can loop through the parent array using `foreach`.

```
string[][] arr = new string[5][];
arr[0] = new string [] { "Round", "Square" };
arr[1] = new string [] { "7", "9", "10" };
arr[2] = new string [] { "Chocklate", "Honey", "Vanila" };
arr[3] = new string [] { "Blank Cake", "Licenced Image Cake", "Personal Image Cake" };
arr[4] = new string [] { "Happy Birthday", "Own Message", "Get Well Soon" };

foreach (var a in arr) {
    Console.WriteLine("Array count:  " +  a.Length);
    //Now you can loop through each child array.
    foreach (string val in a) {
        //Do your stuff.
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + val);
    }
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dzOrRZ)

Comment: I'd show a pseudo-code example, but this is basically it.

Comment: I tried this code. but getting this output, Check screenshot  https://snag.gy/SO19Ur.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This a typical candidate for a recursive implementation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] shape = { "Round", "Square" };
    string[] size = { "7", "9", "10" };
    string[] type = { "Chocklate", "Honey", "Vanila" };
    string[] top = { "Blank Cake", "Licenced Image Cake", "Personal Image Cake" };
    string[] msg = { "Happy Birthday", "Own Message", "Get Well Soon" };

    IEnumerable<string[]> productRows = CartesianProductRecursive(new []{ shape, size, type, top, msg });

    foreach (var row in productRows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string[]> CartesianProductRecursive(IEnumerable<string[]> dimValues)
{
    if (!dimValues.Any())
        yield break;

    string[] firstDimValues = dimValues.First();
    IEnumerable<string[]> lastDimsProduct = CartesianProductRecursive(dimValues.Skip(1));

    if (!lastDimsProduct.Any())
        yield return firstDimValues;

    foreach (string firstDimValue in firstDimValues)
    {
        foreach (string[] lastDimsProductRow in lastDimsProduct)
        {
            yield return new[] {firstDimValue}.Concat(lastDimsProductRow).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are performing tests, you can use [NUnit cartesian product feature](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=combinatorial&r=2.6.4) or  [NCase test case generator](https://github.com/jeromerg/NCase). Both allow to reduce the amount of test cases by generating the pairwise product instead of the cartesian product.