# Descarte's sqaure of array

Tags: c#, linq

How I can get ordered pairs of elements from some array, using LINQ? For example,
I have:

```
int[] d = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

I need:

> { {1, 1}, {1, 2}, ...., {3, 3} }

I tried that LINQ query, but it returns

> { {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3,
>   3} }

```
var pairs = d.SelectMany(a => d.Select(b => new[] { a, b }));
```

Please, help me to find my error.

Comment: The code you've provided yields the sequence you claim to want, not the sequence you're saying it does.

Comment: Are you looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product (which covered already in many questions including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations )? As @Servy code in the post seem to produce result you want...

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var result = d.SelectMany(a => d, Tuple.Create)
              .Where(c=> c.Item1 <= c.Item2).ToArray();
```

Comment: That is beautiful

Comment: @MatiasCicero But the OP didn't state that he wants pairs where the first item is less than the second, so this produces the wrong output.

Comment: @Servy If the OP's code works as he wanted why he should ask a question? Based on his post I think he is looking for a combination that the first item is less than the second or equal.

Comment: @S.Akbari I don't know why he asked the question given that he had the code that generates the code that he wanted, that's why I asked him.  But regardless, he *didn't* ask for this.  This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Servy Compare the OP's desired result and his gotten result. The intersect of both is(the first item is less than the second or equal) But in his desired result I can't see even one item that the second item is less than the first. This was my presumption. BTW I'm waiting for OP's feedback. :)

Comment: @S.Akbari The OP was rather specific about his requirements.  He didn't ask for literally any code that produces a sequence that contains at least the 3 values shown in the output.  If he wanted to exclude values where the first is greater than the second, he would have *stated as much in his requirements*.  Inventing requirements that completely contradict the stated requirements, just because the one, incomplete, example happens to be consistent with your alternate requirements doesn't make your answer correct.

Answer (score -1):

this code work

```
        int[] d = { 1, 2, 3 };

        var query = (from elem1 in d
                     from elem2 in d 
                     where elem1>= elem2
                     select elem1< elem2? new List<int>() { elem1, elem2 }: new List<int>() { elem2, elem1 }
                     ).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: this code work , i have tested, your have { {1, 1}, {1, 2}, ...., {3, 3} } to result