# All combinations with variable loops

Tags: c#, loops

I need find all combinations of several variables.

Example:

I have Field1[] with 3 values: 36, 38, 40. and
Field2[] with values: R, V, A, B.

Then with this code I have all the combinations.

```
for (int x=1;x<=3; x++)
{
    for (int y=1;y<=4;y++)
    {
        debug.print (Field1[x] + "--" + Field2[y]);
    }
}
```

My problem isn't the lenght of "Field1" or "Field2". My problem is that I don't know how many variables "Field1" or "Field2" I have. 
Sometimes I can have more FieldX variables, I don't know how many.

How I can do it??

Thanks

Comment: All arrays in C# have a `.Length` property. Or you could use a `foreach` loop over the arrays, this would also fix the error in your code where you are skipping the first element of each array (and getting an out of bounds exception)

Comment: Are your fields (`Field1`, and `Field2`) really using 1-based indices?  I doubt it.  Are they arrays?  In which case the 3 indices are `0`, `1`, and `2`.  And the loop idiom is `for (int x=0; x<Field1.Length; ++x)`  Note starting at `0` not `1` and comparing with `<` not `<=`.  C# also offers a `foreach` loop that would do the trick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating all Possible Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations)

Comment: My problem isn't the lenght of "Field1" or "Field2". My problem is that I don't know how many variables "Field1" or "Field2" I have

Answer (score 2):

This is a runnable example of it using for and foreach.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = new int[] { 36, 38, 40 };
        var letters = new char[] { 'R', 'V', 'A', 'B' };

        Console.WriteLine("Using for example:");

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < letters.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{numbers[i]} -- {letters[j]}");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Using foreach example:");

        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            foreach (var letter in letters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{number} -- {letter}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Using for example:
> 36 -- R
> 36 -- V
> 36 -- A
> 36 -- B
> 38 -- R
> 38 -- V
> 38 -- A
> 38 -- B
> 40 -- R
> 40 -- V
> 40 -- A
> 40 -- B
> Using foreach example:
> 36 -- R
> 36 -- V
> 36 -- A
> 36 -- B
> 38 -- R
> 38 -- V
> 38 -- A
> 38 -- B
> 40 -- R
> 40 -- V
> 40 -- A
> 40 -- B
> ```

Comment: My problem isn't the lenght of "numbers" or "letters". My problem is that I don't know how many variables "numbers" or "letters" I have.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what your needing...its a List of objects(arrays).
This will give you your count.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ArrayCount
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var numbers = new int[] { 36, 38, 40 };
            var letters = new char[] { 'R', 'V', 'A', 'B' };
            var words = new string[] { "this", "is", "the", "example" };

            List<object> arrayList = new List<object>
            {
                numbers,
                letters,
                words
            };

            Console.WriteLine("    Count:    {0}", arrayList.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("    Values:");
            PrintValues(arrayList);
        }

        public static void PrintValues(List<object> arrayList)
        {
            foreach (object obj in arrayList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", obj);
                foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)obj)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", item.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris. Now I need the combinations between elements of "Numbers", "Letters" and "Words". I need the combinations: "36,R,this", "36,R,is", "36,R,the", "36,R,example", "36,V,this", "36,V,is", "36,V,the", .....

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `Length` of the array

```
for (int x=0; x < Field1.Length; x++)
{
    for (int y=0; y < Field2.Length; y++)
    {
        debug.print (Field1[x] + "--" + Field2[y]);
    }
}
```

Or you can use the `foreach` loop

```
foreach (int x in Field1)
{
    foreach (int y in Field2)
    {
       System.Console.Write($"x:{x} y:{y}");
    } 
}
```

Comment: My problem isn't the lenght of "Field1" or "Field2". My problem is that I don't know how many variables "Field1" or "Field2" I have

Comment: @Karlos Garcia The "length" of the array is how many items it has. Really? Look at ALL the answers...everyone is use the LENGTH.

Comment: Thanks Chris. You're right, but I don't think you understand me. I know the elements in Field1 with Field1.Length. But that's not the problem. The problem is how many Fields do I have. I can have Field1 and Field2, or Field1 and Field2 and Field3, or many FieldX. I don't know how many Field I can have.

Comment: @Karlos Garcia I added another answer that may be what your needing...

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Field1.Length; x++)
{
     for (int y = 0; y < Field2.Length; y++)
         Console.Write(Field1[x] + "--" + Field2[y]);
}
```

Or using LINQ you dont have to care about the `Length` property you can take the cross product and iterate over the same

```
var pairs = (from a in Field1
             from b in Field2
             select new { val1 = a, val2 = b }).ToList();

pairs.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.val1+ "--" + x.val2));
```

Comment: My problem isn't the lenght of "Field1" or "Field2". My problem is that I don't know how many variables "Field1" or "Field2" I have

Comment: In any case the above solution will perfrom the Cartesian Product of the values of FIeld1 & Field2. Its a quadratic operation and will scale badly if you have more than a million records in Field1 & Field2. Since the complexity would be always O(n*m), n being the number of Values in Field1 & m being the number of values in Field2