# How to Enumerate a sequence of unknown size recursively

Tags: c#, recursion, enumeration

I'm trying to write a method that enumerates all sequences that can be used in a for loop.

Assume `IEnumerable<int>[] intValues` is the original collection if integers and let's say it is:

```
intValues[0] = int[] {1, 2, 3}
intValues[1] = int[] {4, 5}
```

I need to write `EnumerateSequences(...)` such that:

```
foreach (int[] seq in EnumerateSequences(...))
{
    // 1st iteration: seq = [1, 4]
    // 2nd iteration: seq = [1, 5]
    // 3rd iteration: seq = [2, 4]
    // 4th iteration: seq = [2, 5]
    // 5th iteration: seq = [3, 4]
    // 6th iteration: seq = [3, 5]
}
```

I came up with this method, however, `EnumerateSequences(intValues, 0, null)` won't recurse inside so it always returns `null`:

```
private static IEnumerable<int[]> EnumerateSequences(IEnumerable<int>[] intValues, int pos, int[] seq) 
{
    if (pos < intValues.Length)
    {
        foreach (var f in intValues[pos])
        {
            if (seq == null && pos == 0)
            {
                seq = new int[intValues.Length];
            }
            seq[pos] = f;
            var _ = EnumerateSequences(intValues, pos + 1, seq);
        }
    }
    else if (pos == intValues.Length || seq == null)
    {
        yield return seq;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing could be easier than "enumerating a sequence" (be it an array, a List , an enum - whatever) in C#.  Q: What exactly are you trying to do, such that you need "recursion" (or some other over-complicated solution)???

Comment: The reason I was using recursion is the size of `IEnumerable<int>[] intValues` is not known prior. The enumeration would be equivalent of a nested for loop, otherwise.

Comment: The example shown in the post is not "sequence of unknown size" (as number of combinations is known).  Are you sure title matches the problem? (so far it indeed looks like duplicate of "get all combinations" despite unrelated title).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov They just mean unknown at compile time, so you can't do `from a in first from b in second from c in third select (a,b,c);`

Comment: What you're looking for is the Cartesian product and Eric Lippert has a blog post about it https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/

Comment: Servy's [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/) and Juharr's [link](https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/) are spot-on.  The original question, as posed, is a great example of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)